# Block editor fails to update HTML section when the word "from" is in source code

Tags: block-editor

I am writing a blog about coding in Swift. Swift has a lot of methods and functions that have `from:` in their function signature.

For example, this line:

```
ret += [String(formatter.string(from: asFloat as NSNumber) ?? "")]
```

For some reason, the editor fails to update, as soon as I get to `from:`

```
ret += [String(formatter.string(fro
```

No problem.

```
ret += [String(formatter.string(from
```

Failed to update.

This is really weird, because, if you look at other posts in the series, you’ll see this all over the place.

I have to assume there’s some kind of security issue going on (maybe anti-spam), but I can’t figure out how to deal with it.

---

I tried turning off all the plugins, and it still happens. I'm not running WordFence, or any other additional security module.

Comment: That's strange. I am not having the same experience in WordPress with the new editor. I'm not able to reproduce.

Comment: Are there JS errors in the console?

Comment: Yes. I do exactly the same thing in many other parts of the blog (It is part of a series, where I keep pasting in copies of the same code). It's definitely some kind of editor bug; probably because security.

Comment: I can't reproduce it ten lines later, pasting in the same code. I was more looking for a workaround, as opposed to a fix.

Comment: I found a workaround. I used the same method that I use to display shortcodes. I inserted a hidden em in the code, like so: "fro<i></i>m". That did it.

Comment: And no. No JS errors.